# How do I remove url.git from my gitconfig?

Tags: git, windows-7

I run `git config -l` and I see a value I do not want:

`url.git://.insteadof=https://`

I tried `git config --unset url.git`.  When I rerun the `git config -l` command the value is still there.  I am running Windows 7.  I went into `C:\Users\bmackey\.gitconfig` and the value is not in there.  Running [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), I do not see any other .gitconfig files on my machine (other than another users file which also does not contain this value).

The value is only showing up in one of my local git repo's. I went into `project\.git\config` and I do not see the value stored in there either.

How can I get rid of this variable?  And (less importantly) where does this value come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typed `git config --global --edit` and this opened up my global `.gitconfig`.  After the VIM editor opened up I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> and this displayed the path to the file.  I saw the nasty little variable in there and deleted it.